# Rust Reference Mods

Tags: module, rust, reference, workspace

I have a set of files in a workspace which I want to reference from another directory, but I cannot find the syntax I need to use.

The example is:

```
Primary
|_______ First
|            |_____ src
|                    |______ Cool_thing.rs
|_______ Second
            |_____ src
                    |______ main.rs
```

I want to reference a struct in `Cool_things` from main.rs

In Primary's Cargo.toml I put:

```
[workspace]
members= ["First","Second", "Third"]

[dependencies.Second]
First= { path = "First" }
```

In the Cargo.toml in the `Second` directory I have

```
[dependencies]
First = { path = "../First" }
```

I have been trying things in my main.rs like:

```
extern crate First;
use First::Cool_things::Cool_things;
```

No variation of `use` or `mod` seems to allow me to reference the struct or impl or functions in mod `Cool_things`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. You have provided no code for "Primary". It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Your file structure doesn't show *any* `Cargo.toml` files; those are required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was it needed a "lib.rs" in the First src directory. Basically, the documentation for rust seems to be a bit remiss in telling people if you want to use local-dependancies then you have to have a lib.rs file which lists all the mods you are planning to access. So the creation of a lib.rs in the First src directory, and listing "Mod Cool_things" would allow the other package to reference the mod files in that directory.

The cargo.toml files: Inserted in the question above had the correct paths and dependancies, the issue was all around the lack of a lib.rs file.

So if you are planning a multiple binary program, you'll need to remember to have a lib.rs file whenever you're breaking up your code and then accessing modules from other parts of the workspace.